# How to programmatically do: " from lib import * " in python

Tags: python, import

i'm searching how to do

```
from myLib import *
```

inside my python code in order to do a import loop

`__import__()` method does not seems to provide the `*` feature, as i have to specify every content i want to import.

Is there a way to do the `*` ?

Thank's a lot for your help

**EDIT:**

to clarify, the goal is to import a bunch of classes, that stand inside a bunch of modules in a package to access them directly through there classes name, not like myPacakge.myModule.myClass(), nor myModule.myClass() but just myClass()

imagine you have:

```
myScript.py
myPackage
    \__init__.py
    \myModule_0.py
    \myModule_1.py
    \myModule_2.py
    \myModule_3.py
    \myModule_4.py
```

each myModule contains a bunch of classes and you are editing myScript.py, you want to have access to all classes in each myModule_X.py like:

```
myClass()
myOtherClass()
myOtherOtherClass()
```

etc... not like myModule_X.myClass() nor myPackage.myModyle_X.myClass()

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this? 99% of the time, you usually know what you're trying to import before you import it, so `from whatever import *` works just fine for that.

Comment: This question screams [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. What is the problem you are trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: I'm confused, why can't you just do import myLib? It's the same idea as import json then doing json.loads(a_variable)

Comment: i have a large bunch of files with a lof of classes & methods inside, i want to import all classes & methods with a loop over all theses files. It's a pain to do from myLib_1 import *,  from myLib_2 import *,  from myLib_3 import *...etc

Comment: i know about package and '_ _ all _ _' but it does not do the trick as if i had a _ _ init _ _.py file with a  _ _ all _ _ with all my files inside, doing from myPackage import * just return me all  _ _ all _ _ module rather than all classes or method within these modules

Comment: imagine you have a package, with a lot of files inside that contains a lot of classes, that you added all these files to _ _ all _ _ variable of you package, and that you just want to access to classes directly from you script without having to write myPackage.myModule.myClass(), not event myModule.myClass() but just myClass() how would you do the import?

Comment: Having dozens of files containing even more classes that you need in one file sounds like a design issue. The file you're doing this import in should probably be broken up in to smaller easier to test and maintain modules or even separate packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__import__` *returns* the imported module's namespace. If you want to do `import *` from it, then you can iterate over that namespace and stuff all the module's names into your module's globals, which is what `from modulename import *` does. You probably *shouldn't,* just like you *shouldn't* use `import *` (except more so because you don't even know what module you're importing) but you *can.*

```
module = __import__("modulename")
if hasattr(module, "__all__"):        # module tells us which names are all names
    globals().update((name, getattr(module, name)) for name in module.__all__)
else:                                 # import all non-private names
    globals().update((name, getattr(module, name)) for name in dir(module) 
                      if not name.startswith("_"))
```

You could also write it like so, which is a little safer since it avoids clobbering any global names already defined (at the risk of potentially not having a name you need):

```
module = __import__("modulename")
if hasattr(module, "__all__"):        # module tells us which names are all names
    globals().update((name, getattr(module, name)) for name in module.__all__
                      if name not in globals())
else:                                 # import all non-private names
    globals().update((name, getattr(module, name)) for name in dir(module) 
                      if not (name.startswith("_") or name in globals()))
```

Comment: i'm trying this, will tell you if it does the job :)

Comment: @repié be VERY sure about what you're doing. This not only will cause confusion but it crowds imports, can lead to naming collisions, it's incredibly difficult to read. Just be absolute that there is not a more elegant approach.

Comment: does not work for me: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'myModule'

Comment: @Obj3ctiv3_C_88 i hope to find a better way, again the goal is to import a bunch of classes that stand inside a package and call them directly by there name rather than module.class() or package.module.class() and import them automatically rather than copy/paste from xxx import *

Comment: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'myModule'` probably means you have something in `__all__` that is not actually defined in the module.

Comment: well... this is the case indeed, module is a package with a `__all__ = ['myModule’]` in it's  `__init.py__` i wish i don't have to set anything else inside it :/

Comment: You should probably define `__all__` dynamically based on what you import from the other files.

Answer (score 0):

```
import myLib
```

will import everything but I advise against an import all

to use it you'd preface all imports with

```
myLib.my_module
```

If you only want to import certain things on the fly you'd want to do a conditional import, eg:

```
if condition_met:
    import myLib.my_module
```

Comment: I'm guessing `myLib` is not the actual name of the module, but is actually an identifier bound to a string that contains the name of the module. Ex. He wants to do `myLib = "math"; do_something(myLib); print sqrt(23)`.

Comment: Wasn't sure since he asked if there was a way to import *, will update answer

Comment: i try to do import in the code, i know basic import stuff and packages, but i want to do programmatically from lib import *

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, programmatically would mean one at a time but importing using * is equivalent to just import myLib which also imports everything.

Comment: imagine you have a package, with a lot of files inside that contains a lot of classes, that you added all these files to _ _ all _ _ variable, and that you just want to access to these classes directly from you script without having to write myPackage.myModule.myClass(), not event myModule.myClass() but just myClass()

Comment: @repié You import by module not package. You have a module, each containing a series of classes, each containing a series of methods. I'm guessing you're wanting to reference a module imported in the module you imported but that is BAD PRACTICE. import * you will likely be cementing it into the module, unable to be removed. This is because it is difficult to determine what items used in the code are coming from 'module', making it easy to get to the point where you think you don't use the import any more but it's extremely difficult to be sure

Answer (score 0):

`import *` wreaks havoc with static code checking and debugging, so I don't recommend using it in a script.  Assuming you're not trying to do something ill-advised with this, you might consider using the `__all__` attribute to get a list of strings of the members of the package.

```
import my_package
for sub_package in my_package.__all__:
    print "found " + sub_package
```

Comment: That's what I said, not sure what they're asking for. Maybe a disconnect in language?